# asp.net text area default value escaping

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, textarea

Note: This is an asp.net page but the XSLT Transformation is occurring client-side.
So I am trying to set a default value in an asp.net textarea and it is being escaped which is causing me problems

Here is the asp.net text area

```
    <asp:TextBox id="Description" TextMode="MultiLine" 
Columns="50" Rows="4" runat="server" 
ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation="false">
<xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" />
</asp:TextBox>
```

On the page it becomes

```
<textarea id="Description" cols="50" rows="4" 
name="ctl00$RightColumn$Description">
&lt;xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" /&gt;
</textarea>
```

Putting in the text area the literally

```
<xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" />
```

I'd like to get the non escaped value in there.... if i Just use a regular text area like

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="5">
<xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" />
</textarea>
```

It works fine.... How can I accomplish this with an ASP.NET control? It's basically breaking my clientside xslt but ONLY on the textarea...

Thanks!

Note: I also did try using the text="{/oohru/form/desc}" inside of the text area... same thing the text area contained that exact oohru/form/desc rather than the referenced value.

Comment: The solution ended up being 
`<textarea rows="4" cols="50" 
id="Description" runat="server">
<xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" />
</textarea>`

inside of the cs file when I need to reference the value it is
`Description.InnerText`

Hope this helps anyone in the future with a similar problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use XSLT too-late.

**My guess is that you want to generate the control with XSLT**.

In this case *inside your XSLT transformation* you'll have:

```
<asp:TextBox id="Description" TextMode="MultiLine"  
             Columns="50" Rows="4" runat="server"  
             ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation="false"> 

   <xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" /> 
</asp:TextBox>
```

where you'll also need to bind the prefix `asp:` to some namespace.

**Alternatively, *within the XSLT transformation* you can generate the `textarea` directly**:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="5">  
  <xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" />  
</textarea>
```

**Final note**: If my guesses are wrong and you just want the end-user to see in the `textarea` the string `"<xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" />"`, then it doesn't matter that you see it(before being displayed by the browser) escaped -- when the browser displays it, the user will see the unescaped text.

**Update**: @Jordan has further clarified his transformation is client-side -- way after the asp control has evaporated...

**In this case the answer is**: No, you cannot generate with the `asp:TextBox` control any markup (node other than a text node) inside the `textarea`-- it only generates text inside it.

Therefore, you have to generate explicitly the `textarea` and the `<xsl:value-of>` on the server.

Comment: I am actually doing the transformation client side.  I should have specified... so i cannot create the control with XSLT.  The regular text area works fine... I had just hoped to use a .net control so I'd not have to write some of the validation and such.

Comment: @Jordan, I updated my answer on this new information. You can't use the `asp:TextBox` to generate anything else than text inside the `textarea`.

Comment: Much Appreciated. Just as an FYI you can do it in a textbox just not a multi-line one....
as an example
`<asp:TextBox ID="Oohrl" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"  ClientIDMode="Static" Text="{/oohru/form/oohrl}"></asp:TextBox>`
Works fine generating the actual value held by /oohru/form/oohrl and not that literal text.  For some reason the text area is treated differently.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you can do this with ASP -- it behaves almost as XSLT :)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the Text property of TextBox control to this value in code-behind. That might work. BTW what is xsl and what you want to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

XSL and ASP.NET aren't really friends.

You can try something like what you'll find [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/57bbe853-6dd1-4fd9-9a70-e6fb3b021418/), but if you can - port your xsl to a resource file.